# Python getting post data to call remote python script to display on page

Tags: javascript, php, python-3.x, post, ssh

I am pretty new to python as I've been using PHP in the past. I am trying to practice python by converting my PHP code to python. I have the following php code to receive POST data from webserver and make a call over ssh to output a text file of a remote server back to the page.

app.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").on('click', function() {
    //call python script to generate report
     $.get("/", function(data){
        $( "#statusOutput" ).val(data);
    });
});
});
```

gettextoutput.php:

```
<?php //gettextoutput.php

    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'pass';
    $path = '/path/to/my/text/file';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $hostname = $_POST['hostname']; //10.139.x.x
        $textoutput = file_get_contents("ftp://$user:$password@$hostname/$path");
        echo $textoutput; // I can use this to display the text output back to the page
    }
?>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this in python as well? Any information would be appreciated!

Comment: You would need to use a WSGI server, you may try to use flask with built-in werkzeug to try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you on the path to do it. using Flask and FTPlib that you must install. This works with a server named werkzeug (WSGI) out of the box included in Flask.

```
#This answers makes a few assumptions | assumes a payload in json format | assumes Flask as framework | Assumes werkzeug as a WSGI server
from Flask import Flask, request, send_file
from ftplib import FTP                                                                      

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods['POST'])
def get_some_file():
    input = request.get_json()
    ftp = FTP("SOMESERVERFTPIP")                                                                               
    ftp.login(input['user'],input['password'])
#This will create local file and write contents of ftp file to it
    with open(/local/path/+input['path'], 'w') as f:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % input['path'], f.write)

    #Filename should be a path, you may concatenate etc..
    return send_file('/local/path'/+input['filename'],
                     mimetype='text/txt',
                     attachment_filename='filename',
                     as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It seems like there is much more code involved in python than PHP ;)

Comment: well this could obviously be improved and code reduced, this was meant as a guideline. This also sends a file, and not the ouptut, something that would reduce text if you only "echo" the file.

Comment: Thanks again! Could you show how I could read the content and just echo it back to the browser so i can display it on the page as well? Also, I noticed that you put the username and password in the code above, is there a better and secure way of doing this ?

Comment: For some reason when i trigger the button press event on the JS side, it just returns the index page in my statusoutput textbox. I added the javascript code above, am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: This will download a file when you trigger it. So instead of setting the send_file method, add an import to make_response, and add return make_response("This should be a var containing the text", 200 (This is the status_code(int))) 

You also need to read the file contents, to that var.